# Custom view with animation drawable

Tags: android, animation, android-custom-view

I want to create a custom view which should have animation. I want to draw the circle with specifying the radius and some drawable element in this custom view which should be moving in this circle.

I know how to draw a circle, how to add a drawable element, but I don`t know how to animate this drawable element.

Should I write animation methods in custom view or better to create another class with animation logics and apply it to my custom view. Can you give me some advice?

I think that second case is wrong because in this way a whole view will be animating, but not only drawable.